# Batch File Rd Error: The directory is not empty

Tags: batch-file, del, rmdir

I've been working on a code to delete the files from a Location inputted in .txt file.

```
@echo off  
cd C:\Users\Troy\Desktop\Details  
set /p loc=<Location.txt  
rd /s /q "%loc%"  
echo %loc%  
pause
```

This code returns me the following output

```
The directory is not empty.
C:\Users\Troy\Downloads\TV Shows    
Press any key to continue ...
```

Now the file Location.txt, when opened contains following
C:\Users\Troy\Downloads\TV Shows which is in accordance with the echo output I get in the second line (of the above output)

Also note that I have saved the batch file at C:\Users\Troy\Desktop
So there arises no reason for any interference due to the same location.

The weird part is when I run the following code from another batch file at the same location it runs perfectly fine and deletes all the files.

```
@echo off  
set loc=C:\Users\Troy\Downloads\TV Shows  
rd /s /q "%loc%"  
echo %loc%  
pause
```

So the only difference between the two codes is that the first one sets the variable location from a specific file, whereas the other one has a pre- inputted variable.

Also I have tried to delete files from the location using the following code

```
@echo off  
cd C:\Users\Troy\Desktop\Details  
set /p loc=<Location.txt  
cd %loc%
del /s /q * >nul 2>&1
cd C:\Users\Troy\Desktop\Details
rd /s /q "%loc%"  
echo %loc%  
pause
```

In the above code, the delete command works perfectly fine and deletes all the files within. However folders and subfolders are all that are left, which means that `rd` command is not working

I've even tried the `attrib -h` thing, but that does not work either.
Also note that I've tried this with various permutations and combinations of `rmdir /s /q` too. But does not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that the directory tree is empty, `DIR/B/S/A "%loc%"` If there's something there you weren't expecting to see then I'd suggest you use a more sure fire `ERASE` command on the directories first; `DEL/F/S/Q/A "%loc%\*"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried doing what you said, however ended up with the same result. Could you check if it happens with your device as well ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no intention of trying to replicate something for which I'm relatively clueless. I've have however seen this problem before, still with no real idea of the cause. The solution at the time was to run the command again, so after your `rd` command try to add an new line, `If Exist "%loc%\" RD/S/Q "%loc%"`. Not ideal but it has inexplicably been known to work.

Comment: Check the presence of spaces at the end of the variable definition and inside the `.txt` file. The `cd` command is less restrictive than the `rd` with the ending spaces.

Comment: @MCND Thanks Man. I spent all of my day figuring out what was wrong with the code. But apparently the extra spacing at the end of the location file was the deterrent. Thanks again, you guys really are geniuses.

Answer (score 0):

You could be suffering from some corruption in the file system. Try running `chkdsk /f`. You'll have to reboot in order to run it, but see if it finds something that it can correct, then see if your problem goes away.